# How to set up Azure Spatial Anchors with Unity Android project?

Tags: unity, c#, android, augmented-reality

I'm building an AR app in which I wish to use Microsoft's Azure and it's web service Spatial Anchors. I cannot seem to get the sample demo, which I downloaded from https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples, to work for storing spatial anchors on the external server.

Following their tutorial I can create the Azure account, set up the resource group and individual Spatial Anchors resource. However, in the Unity project, there is a config file called 'AzureSpatialAnchorsDemoConfig' which requires that you specify an account id(I have this), a primary key(i also have this), and a base sharing url: which is what I am struggling to find and is what I assume is the cause of being unable to store my anchors to the cloud.

This is a snippet from the tutorial that I'm having issues with, if I fill in the address in my web browser I can't even find that ip.

> In the Inspector pane, enter the Sharing Anchors Service url (from your ASP.NET web app Azure deployment) as the value for Base Sharing Url, replacing index.html with api/anchors. It should look like this:
>
> https://<app_name>.azurewebsites.net/api/anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to another tutorial, based on the same git repo's sample, after the creation of the resource, there also needs to be an Azure Cosmos DB resource to create the base sharing URL.

For anyone reading this that got stuck this is where you get the three values you need for demo config:

1. Under your azure portal, locate the spatial anchors resource from your dashboard
2. Account ID is located on the right hand side of the overview pane
3. Primary key is in the keys page.
4. Deploy an Azure Cosmos DB from the spatial anchors sample solution, using
   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-share-anchors-across-devices
5. The base sharing URL is https://<>.azurewebsites.net/api/anchors

Where <> is the name of the web service you deployed with the tutorial in 4